# The c.vim c/c++ plugin puts the return value of a function above the function, is that alright?

Tags: c++, c, vim, coding-style

```
void
foo()
{
}
```

That's what I get.

I only recently have ventured into the waters of GNU, etc, so maybe I am just too inexperienced, but...

I have never seen this convention before.
What's the deal with it? Does it give some editor related benefits? Or human benefits? 
Like knowing that each function name starts at column 1?

Edit:
I did find one website mentioning that it is 'okay' to do this, but it seems this is not a convention used often.

Guess the author just prefers this style, making me realize why this question might have been downvoted at the start.

Comment: I have seen this style before, but I don't use it.  The default vim settings include code formatting and syntax highlighting if you have the right lines in your vimrc (try adding `:set syntax on`, `:set smartindent`, and `:set filetype on` to your vimrc), so I don't use c.vim.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Well, it does seem that that style is used, but apparently not often. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've worked with coworkers that *loved* this style and I have to admit that the ability to find a function via `grep -R ^foo .` is compellingly cool but nearly any program that grows to three or more source files is best navigated in conjunction with `etags`, `gid`, or `cscope` (I like a combination of all three), so the benefit to simple `grep` use isn't as compelling as it might have been once upon a time.

Comment: It's also easier to find a specific function when quickly scanning over a file since the function name starts at the same place.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that style dates back from pre-ansi C.
Ever see the following declaration of main (I have seen this style used in gnu source code)?

```
main(argc, argv)
int arc;
char *argv[];
{
    return 0;
}
```

Because `int` used to be the default return value, only when you need to specify you did, like your example on a different line.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense, guess the plugin was meant to be as conventional as possible then.

Answer (score 2):

The C/C++ compiler doesn't care about the extra newline, it'll just treat it like any other whitespace, so syntactically it's fine (but the preprocessor does care, so you can't put newlines halfway through macros without escaping them)

Stylistically, I don't like it much, but its proponents probably like being able to search the file for lines starting with their function name.

Answer (score 2):

When I get a template that looks like that, the first thing I do is delete those newlines in an attempt to make the code more manageable. It happens all the time with bada.